# Delete from cursor to the beginning of a line in insert mode

Tags: key-bindings, vimrc

In insert mode I want to delete all text from the cursor to the beginning of a line and stay in insert mode.

Here is the mapping I tried:

```
inoremap DD <ESC>c0
```

and this *almost* works. In the following line (in ***insert mode***)

```
This is a test line 
              ^
           cursor
```

in insert mode cursor goes 1 step further than just typed symbol (***t*** in my case). And if I press ***DD***, I will get

```
t line
```

but want just

```
 line
^
cursor
```

***with*** the space the cursor pointed.

Is there a way to do this in vim?

Comment: just move right first then...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's actually already a builtin for this. `:h i_<C-u>`:

```
                *i_CTRL-U*
CTRL-U          Delete all entered characters in the current line (see
    |i_backspacing| about joining lines).
```

You could map this, e.g.

```
inoremap DD <C-u>
```

But this might interfere with typing. I would encourage you to just learn to use `<C-u>` instead.